# Create and manage marketplace managed application Azure B2C tenant in bicep

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-bicep

I'm currently working on Azure Marketplace app. So far, I was able to remodel all of the required infrastructure resources using bicep, unfortunately I hit the wall when trying to create a managed B2C tenant for specific deployment.

I am able to create the tenant using the following bicep code:

```
resource b2cTenant 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2021-04-01' = {
  name: directoryName
  location: tenantLocation
  sku: {
    name: skuName
    tier: skuTier
  }
  properties: {
    createTenantProperties: {
      countryCode: 'AU'
      displayName: '${organizationName} ADB2C Tenant'
    }
  }
  tags: tags
```

This results in a new tenant, which I can access from managed resource group using portal.

However, I need to configure this tenant by setting up app registrations, creating admin accounts for the application and so on.
As far as I am concerned, currently it's not possible using bicep, but I was pointed to a workaround utilizing deploymentScript, like so:

```
resource managedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: 'DeploymentScript'
  location: location
  tags: tags
}

resource adminRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' existing = {
  scope: subscription()
  name: '8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635'
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  scope: b2cTenant
  name: guid(resourceGroup().id, managedIdentity.id, adminRoleDefinition.id)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: adminRoleDefinition.id
    principalId: managedIdentity.properties.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}

resource b2cDeploymentScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'b2cDeploymentScript'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzurePowerShell'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    azPowerShellVersion: '3.0'
    scriptContent: loadTextContent('./scripts/register-b2c-app.ps1')
    retentionInterval: 'PT4H'
    cleanupPreference: 'OnSuccess'
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to execute the actions against newly provisioned tenant, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403
> (Forbidden).

When I check the token fetched in powershell script using

```
$Token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com -Verbose).Token
```

I see that `tid (tenant id)` is the main tenant id.
Since managed identity has admin role, I figured I could manually specify the tenant using

```
Set-AzContext -TenantId $TenantId -Subscription $SubscriptionId -Verbose
```

or

```
(Get-AzAccessToken -TenantId $TenantId -ResourceTypeName MSGraph -Verbose).Token
```

but the I get the following error:

> Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated.
> (Code:RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted)

Also, I bumped into [this site](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.resources/deployment-script-azcli-graph-azure-ad/README.md), which states:

> As of October 2022, you can't use Bicep or ARM templates to grant Microsoft Graph permissions to a user-assigned managed identity. Before the deployment runs, you need to create a user-assigned managed identity, and grant it the appropriate permisions to the Graph API.

This makes no sense, it renders creating a tenant with bicep useless!
Has anyone successfully provisioned and was able to set up managed application B2C? Actually I'm also open to any workaround, just hoping this doesn't force us to ditch B2C entirely as we need an identity provider per deployment.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, it does make sense: Azure != AzureAD/Entra. Settings for app registrations are made in Entra, not in Azure. You can use the MS Graph api to create an appreg and setup permissions.

Comment: Right, but I still need to do this from deploymentScript during the marketplace managed application deployment. Do you know how can I authenticate against the API for tenant created with bicep?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the created b2c tenant ? would be interest to see who is global admin: maybe the SP running the bicep? Not familiar with managed app in market place but you have access to the SP running the dpeloyment or is it managed by azure or by whoever is actually dpeloying the app ?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure if I get it right, but deployment script is run by managed identity with Owner role. It is created with bicep and managed by azure. The deployment is triggered with azure portal using Service catalog managed application. Since a managed identity is an owner of the B2C tenant I would assume I could get AD B2C token to register applications, set up accounts etc.

Comment: Here you are creating a new AAD tenant and owner is not the same as global admin. Did you manage to connect to a newly created b2c tenant ?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reply! What do you mean by connect to a new b2c tenant? I can access it locally and run all the scripts against it (no problem with authentication, also I can switch az-context to the new tenant), but trying to authenticate in a newly created tenant in deployment script results in 403. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Can you access the newly created tenant through azure portal ?

Comment: When I was testing it locally using New-AzResourceGroupDeployment with the same template file, I could. However now, when I run the deployment from Service catalog managed application, it seems it cannot even create a b2c tenant, returning `You do not have permission to view this directory or page` on b2c deployment step. Btw. are you aware of any information if deploying a b2c tenant as an identity provider for azure marketplace app is even an option? Thanks!